# Can't connect through WiFi, but possible through Mobile Data

Tags: java, php, android, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I've a `php` file named `test.php` stored in my `Openshift` server (http://phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com/v1/test.php) with the below code.

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
```

**Task**

I am trying to download the text from an Android application.

**Problem**

I am getting a `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com": No address associated with hostname` while connecting  through a `WiFi` network, but everything is fine with `Mobile Data`.

**Android Activity Code**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        final TextView tvTest  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    final URL url = new URL("http://phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com/v1/test.php");
                    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(line).append("\n");
                    }

                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Error: "  + e.getMessage();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                tvTest.setText(result);
            }
        }.execute();

    }
```

**RESPONSES**

**on WiFi**

[image: onWiFi]

**on Mobile Data**

[image: onMobileData]

**Question**

1) Why I can't connect through the `WiFi network` where `Mobile Data` is perfectly fine ?

2) How to solve this problem ?

**NOTE:** Sometime it's getting connected, sometime won't.

Comment: Have you made sure that the wifi router is connected to internet? i.e Were you able to access the url http://phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com/v1/test.php from a  device/computer connected to the same wifi ?

Comment: Yeah am pretty sure about the internet connection and the url is accessible from the device.

Comment: I think you have remaining Android Manifest permission for _ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE_
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: I don't think so, anywayz here's the manifest http://pastebin.com/reqDaPdb

Comment: Why should i have the `Network state permission` ? I think we just need the `Internet` permission to access the internet and the `Network state permission` needed only when we want to check the `STATE` of the internet. isn't ?

Comment: @ShifarShifz Try to open the url in the mobile browser once. If it didn't open there it might be your wifi have some issue(may be the ip is blocked etc) or you may try some different wifi connection for the testing.

Comment: Have you tried other phones yet? I have tested your code in my phone with my Wifi, it works!

Comment: You can try uninstalling any app relating to the network in your phone, such as firewall, net monitor, or even reset your phone if needed... then retry. I think your phone has problem, not the wifi networks (because you confirmed having tested with many wifi)

Comment: One more thing, make sure your tested wifi networks can access Internet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your DNS doesn't know the IP address of the requested site.**

You are experiencing problems, because the DNS of your Wifi connection cannot convert a hostname to an IP address. 
And your data carrier is using different DNS which has associated IP address to hostname.

Try to change your DNS server address on your Wifi router or use direct IP address of the website if available.

**Here are some google DNS server addresses**

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Comment: I can't connect from any `WiFi` connection . I think people using my `App` won't be changing their `WiFi` configuration for a specific application. What can i do now ?

Comment: I am on wifi and I can see hello message.

Comment: @Shifar Please check your router DNS settings and it should work. I can see it using the wifi

Comment: @ShifarShifz [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/EBAD7vz.png?1), your code is working on my phone over WiFi.

Comment: The DNS will update automatically but can take up to 48 hours in special cases, usually within `4 hours`. You could change the DNS to the DNS of Google (`8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`). This only works if the problem is indeed the DNS. Which I think is **NOT** the case.

Answer (score 4):

You may have an IPv4 vs IPv6 problem. Many mobile data plans use IPv6, while most WiFi installations currently use IPv4, so you may be switching more than just the network layer; you may actually be switching layer 3 protocols.

The DNS entry for phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com points to an IPv4 address (only), so it *should* work on WiFi. But maybe your mobile device uses an IPv6 DNS server and can't resolve the name via IPv4?

Another possibility: your mobile device may have a more general problem in the IPv4 stack. Your mobile data may be using one of the 6-to-4 transition technologies and thus bypass your local IPv4 problem.

I noticed another problem with the DNS name phpgear-shifz.rhcloud.com although I doubt it is related.

That DNS entry is actually a CNAME entry that points to another CNAME entry, which in turn points to an A record on Amazon. Double indirections of CNAMEs are a violation of the DNS RFCs, although most resolver should handle it anyway. Also, if this was the problem, it should affect both WiFi and mobile data equally.